# WordPress Import shows an error when uploading previously exported xml file

Tags: import

First time I faced this problem & trying to find out solution but it seems to me that it happens very few and that is why no more solution has been found like this & that is why I am here.

WordPress Import Message:

> File is empty. Please upload something more
>   substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled
>   in your `php.ini` or by `post_max_size` being defined as smaller than
>   `upload_max_filesize` in `php.ini`.

I am getting above message when trying to import a previously imported file like the bellow image. Could you please tell me how to solve this?

[image]

I already tried to find the solution by googling but could not yet?

Comment: the error itself states the problem, did you checked `upload_max_filesize`? are you working on local server like xampp etc?

Comment: yes, i am working in localhost but i exported the file from live server. but where is the file size declaration? -thanks

Comment: learn how to google : [See this](http://www.codecheese.com/2013/12/the-uploaded-file-exceeds-the-upload_max_filesize-directive-in-php-ini-fix-error/), tell me one more thing how much space is left in your dirve where you've installed local server?

Comment: i added my answer below with a brief

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increase the upload limit in your `php.ini`.

To increase the maximum upload file size, open your php.ini file in the "`xampp/php/php.ini`" directory. search for `upload_max_filesize` and increase the value like :

```
upload_max_filesize = 128M
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix this problem, you need to navigate into your cpanel and change the PHP functions to increase the size.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGJrlvV_vQ4

Comment: In the comments on the question, it was stated that this was happening in a localhost context. I don't think cpanel was the issue here.